# Android SDK bundle fails to build new projects

Tags: android, eclipse

just installed the latest and greatest Android SDK bundle from Google on OSX. After I've upgraded ADT from 22.6.2 to 22.6.3 the build process always fails with:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'xxxx'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Restart eclipse? Restart your system ?

Comment: Thanks, but already tried and no success.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Apparently it was a problem with the Java 7 SDK and ADT 22.6.3 . I've installed SDK 8, cleaned up the applications cache from ~/Library/Caches and now it works.